When to provision higher iops or throughput on gp3
We have an AWS PostgreSQL RDS instance. Not a lot of users, high loads in the overnight batch jobs.
Current instance type is m6g.large (2CPU 8GiB RAM) with 1300 GB Storage on gp3 SSD with 12000 IOPS and a storage throughput of 500 MiBps.
We have issues in the nightly batches with EBS Byte Balance depleting.
Should we increase either IOPS or the storage throughput? To what metrics do we need to look to decide if we should increase one of those?
Or should we upgrade the instance type to m6g.xlarge? The latter has higher EBS Optimized Baseline bandwidth.
